# How to let users edit just the text and photos of the Odoo website?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-website

Me as an admin created a website in Odoo. How can I let some users to edit the text and photos on the website and nothing else? I mean the static text on the landing page, banner image and things like these.

I tried to add writing access to  access_website_ir_ui_view_publisher access rule but the changes made by the user cannot be saved on the website. (After pressing save button nothing happens)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the controller, that get the form inputs from the website.
Then, you have to override this controller's route-def, in order to filter your user accordingly.
Moreover, you have to grant access to the  models, that are involved in the website-editor's snippets (for example: for Newsletter-snippet, the "mass.mailing" model is involved...)